# Type 'UploadMappingFileTask' property 'googleServicesResourceRoot' doesn't have a configured value

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

After updating the classpath I can no longer build a release version of the app.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileRelease' (type 'UploadMappingFileTask').
  - Type 'UploadMappingFileTask' property 'googleServicesResourceRoot' doesn't have a configured value.
    
    Reason: This property isn't marked as optional and no value has been configured.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Assign a value to 'googleServicesResourceRoot'.
      2. Mark property 'googleServicesResourceRoot' as optional.



    A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileRelease' (type 'UploadMappingFileTask').
  - Type 'UploadMappingFileTask' property 'googleServicesResourceRoot' doesn't have a configured value.
```

I tried to read the changelog but no guidelines or documentation about it.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

To fix it, the Google Services plugin should be applied before any Firebase plugin in `/app/build.gradle`.

This produces the error:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
```

While this does not:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf
```

Note that `com.google.gms.google-services` is **ABOVE** `com.google.firebase.crashlytics`.

When you update to `com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.0` and sync the changes, you are given a message stating that is the fix as follows:

```
Configure project :app
Crashlytics could not find Google Services plugin task: processReleaseGoogleServices. Make sure com.google.gms.google-services is applied BEFORE com.google.firebase.crashlytics. If you are not using the Google Services plugin, you must explicitly declare `googleServicesResourceRoot` inputs for Crashlytics upload tasks.
```

Comment: I remember to put that line at the bottom (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38202698/3559908))... Now it's changed again...

Comment: @Vall0n They changed it in the documentation to be in the very top:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_the_sdk

Comment: Fixed the issue, but gradle starts showing a warning: "Warning: Please apply google-services plugin at the bottom of the build file." :)

Answer (score 22):

Make sure

```
'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

is applied before:

```
'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

Fixed the error for me.

Comment: this did a trick for new versions but in previous versions it's not an issue.

Answer (score 5):

I also didn't found anything, for now changing to firebase-crashlytics-gradle to 2.6.1 seems ok.

Comment: What a pain support

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @casolorz they are looking at it here https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2721

Comment: Thanks, I switched back to 2.6.1 and that works for now.

Answer (score 5):

This happened for me when I was testing `minifyEnabled true` in my `debug` builds.

Adding the following to my debug buildTypes resolved the issue for me.

```
      firebaseCrashlytics
          {
            mappingFileUploadEnabled false
          }
```

Comment: This is to avoid uploading the ProGuard mapping in every build which requires internet that can slow your iteration.

Answer (score 1):

My project didn't use `'com.google.gms.google-services'`. You need to add `'com.google.gms.google-services'` to the app level Gradle file in the plugins and, its corresponding classpath dependency `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:latest-version'` in the project level Gradle file.

Also make sure `com.google.gms.google-services` comes before `com.google.firebase.crashlytics` as stated by other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I already had the apply plugin lines in the correct order, yet I was still getting the build error and sync warning about the plugin task not being found. I considered the possibility of upgrading google-services, but version 4.1.0 was as high as I could make it. Any higher, and I would get errors about library dependencies not being found.

It turned out not only did I need to upgrade google-services to 4.3.14, defining the `mavenCentral()` repository in the project-level build.gradle wasn't enough; it also needed to be defined in the app-level build.gradle.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral() // Add this line
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

Nowhere in the Get Started documentation did it mention needing to do this, so hopefully, this will help anyone who gets stuck in the same situation I was in.