# firebase-crashlytics-gradle plugin fails with exception 'googleServicesResourceRoot' doesn't have a configured value

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics-android

After applying the crashlytics plugin 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' to my project,
my build fails with an exception:

```
// build.gradle.kts
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1")
    }
}

apply(plugin = "com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
```

```sh
$ ./gradlew

...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':platforms:mobile:android:app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileCglDevRelease' (type 'UploadMappingFileTask').
  - In plugin 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' type 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.gradle.tasks.UploadMappingFileTask' property 'googleServicesResourceRoot' doesn't have a configured value.
    
    Reason: This property isn't marked as optional and no value has been configured.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Assign a value to 'googleServicesResourceRoot'.
      2. Mark property 'googleServicesResourceRoot' as optional.
```

How can I avoid this gradle exception without using the google-play-services plugin and still have a successful obfuscation mapping uploaded to firebase crashlytics?

What is the firebase-crashlytics-gradle plugin expecting from `googleServicesResourceRoot`? Build flavor resources root? The directory where the `google-services.json` file is located at? (which I don't use)?

I found [Type 'UploadMappingFileTask' property 'googleServicesResourceRoot' doesn't have a configured value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67865303/type-uploadmappingfiletask-property-googleservicesresourceroot-doesnt-have), with the same root cause and an accepted solution, which is to apply the google-play-services plugin prior to the crashlytics plugin.

However, we are not using the google-play-services plugin and we don't intend to do it in the future.

Comment: Did you find a solution? We are in exactly the same position.

Comment: I did not find a proper solution, but as a (hopefully temporary) workaround, I had to enabled the undesired google-play-plugin

Answer (score 3):

We're also not using the google services plugin and were getting this error at first. To fix it we did this:

For each flavor that we want to connect to Firebase and Crashlytics we have an xml resource file named `values.xml` containing the required Firebase properties (`project_id`, `google_app_id`, `google_crash_reporting_api_key`, etc) in the resource files `values` folder (e.g. `app/src/prodRelease/res/values/values.xml`).

In the app level `build.gradle.kts` we have:

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    tasks.withType<UploadMappingFileTask> {
        val myDirProp = project.objects.directoryProperty().fileValue(file("src/prodRelease/res"))
        googleServicesResourceRoot.value(myDirProp)
    }
}
```

This sets the `googleServicesResourceRoot` and successfully uploads the mapping file to Crashlytics.